# I can not find the payment method in the dirty menu backoffice

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

I can not find the payment method in the dirty menu backoffice

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There would be 3 reasons for this.

1. As pointed out by another answer, your assigned user login does not have the permissions to use Payment Methods. Have someone with full administrative rights add it to your assigned role.
2. Payment Methods module output has been disabled. This will have been done in System=>Config=>Advanced or by setting the `<active>` node to false in the module control file in `app/etc/modules`
3. This was a Magento Connect install and it only did a partial job of installation so Magento components are missing.

Comment: 4. core modules like `Mage_Payment` are deactivated via XML in `app/etc/modules` - any file there can contain `<Mage_Payment><active>false</active></Mage_Payment>` and thus disable the module completely (you still see it in system > config > advanced, so don't rely on that)

Comment: Yeah, I have a `Zzz_Disable.xml` file for that kind of thing... Something to watch for.

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer..in app/etc/modules file mage all mage like that : <active>true</active>

Comment: Zzz_Disable.xml ? how I can use ?it can help me to solve this problem?